# CMake could not find JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, cmake

I created a new Android Studio Project with C++ support and did not add anything to it. The project builds, compiles and runs with CMake. I then added the following two lines of code to `CMakeLists.txt` at the bottom of the file and I get a CMake build error.

```
find_package(Java COMPONENTS Development)       # Line 47
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)                      # Line 48
```

And this is the error I get when building the project

```
-- Found Java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-oracle/bin/java (found version "10.0.1") found components:  Development 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at /home/xxxxx/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY
See also "/home/xxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/x86_64/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindJNI.cmake:314 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (find_package)
External native generate JSON release: JSON generation completed with problems
```

CMake runs when being called form the command line, but fails inside Android Studio for some reason and I am not sure why.

**EDIT 1**

Here is the [CMakeOutput.log](https://pastebin.com/vZXfkPya) file

**EDIT 2**

This is all that is in `CMakeLists.txt` file. It compiles in cmd with the command cmake.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

find_package(Java COMPONENTS Development)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
```

This is the cmd output

```
    E:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build>cmake ..
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/Users/xxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build
```

When I try to add it compile it in Android Studio using gradle I get the following error on Windows 10 pro 64 bit

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

E:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication>gradlew build --stacktrace

> Task :app:generateJsonModelDebug 
External native generate JSON debug: starting JSON generation
External native generate JSON debug: using platform version 24 for ABI ARMEABI_V7A and min SDK version 24
External native generate JSON debug: noticing that build file 'E:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\CMakeLists.txt' is out of date with respect to E:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\.extern
alNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\android_gradle_build.json
External native generate JSON debug: rebuilding JSON E:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\android_gradle_build.json due to:
External native generate JSON debug: - a dependent build file changed
External native generate JSON debug: keeping json folder 'E:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a' but regenerating project
External native generate JSON debug: executing cmake Executable : E:\Android\SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe
arguments :
-HE:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app
-BE:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a
-DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=E:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-DANDROID_NDK=E:\Android\SDK\ndk-bundle
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=E:\Android\SDK\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=E:\Android\SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe
-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja
jvmArgs :


CMake Error at E:/Android/SDK/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY
  JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/Android/SDK/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  E:/Android/SDK/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindJNI.cmake:314 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/Users/xxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: How does this question differ from your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030811/cmake-could-not-find-jni)?

Comment: Becuase the last one was trying to compile a GitHub C++ repo which had a Java binding dependency and this one is just trying to figure out why CMake won't find JNI in Android Studio.

Comment: In the configuration output, `See also` message shouldn't break "missing" list of variables.

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand your comment. What should not be breaking?

Comment: Lines `Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY`, `JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)` **compound single message**, so no "See also " line should come between them. Correct lines sequence can be observed in your previous(deleted) question.

Comment: I just made a second edit where the output is consistent with the older one. I am not sure why it was different at first.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I also tried using the terminal in Android Studio to use cmake and it gives the same output as the cmd test. So I think the problem is somewhere in the linking of cmake and gradle, but I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: This problem appears when you use headless jdk

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY
```

Solved with

```
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt-get install -y default-jdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: looks like it's still `openjdk-8-jdk` as of Feb 2020

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try re-running with `-DBUILD_JAVA=ON`  

E.g., `cmake .. -DBUILD_GSTREAMER_PLUGIN=ON -DBUILD_JNI=TRUE -DBUILD_JAVA=ON`

Comment: `yum install java-latest-openjdk-devel` on my CentOS server

Comment: Yes setting the `JAVA_HOME` fixed this for me on OSX. One issue I had was that CMake had found the JRE the first time it ran so it wasn't responding the the `JAVA_HOME`. After I deleted `CMakeCache.txt` it ran perfectly.

Answer (score 28):

As the CMake version bundled with Android tries to tell you, it can't find the JNI package because some parts were missing:

```
missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Checking the documentation for FindJNI (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJNI.html) these variables are set to the locations of libraries and headers not shipped with the Android version of JNI (to little surprise, Android does not included the AWT library for instance).
When running `find_package(JNI REQUIRED)`, the FindJNI code checks if these variables are set and if not, issues an error.

A workaround is to set these variables yourself, before calling `find_package`:

```
# We are only interested in finding jni.h: we do not care about extended JVM
# functionality or the AWT library.
set(JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY NotNeeded)
set(JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY NotNeeded)
set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 NotNeeded)
set(JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH NotNeeded)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
```

Be aware though, that your code will only be able to use *jni.h* and its functionality: if it tries to access any other part of the JNI package it will fail (probably at compile time) because essentially, you have tricked CMake into thinking that the entire package was found, when in reality only a part of it exists in the Android setup.

Comment: Thank you so much for this another `NotNeeded` `cmake`  voodoo. What do you mean by, `if it tries to access any other part of of the JNI package ...` ? I'm only interested in hooking my `C++` to `Java` and `JNI` does that. What else is offered by `JNI` by the way aside from allowing `C++` to link to Java??

Comment: If you only need the JNI header you're fine.  On the other hand if you need to link against the `JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY`, the `JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY` or include the header from `JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH`, those will fail.  `FindJNI.java` should probably be updated for this, since the OP's error seems to be rather standard these days.

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution that works for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project("ktaglib")

set(JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/lib/libjawt.so")
set(JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/lib/server/libjvm.so")

set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")
set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/linux")
set(JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")

find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
```

You must set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"` beforehand.

More info: https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross/issues/576

Answer (score 0):

Same on alpine:edge docker image, fixed using:

```
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk8
```

ref: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=openjdk8&arch=x86_64&repo=community

Answer (score 0):

The `FindJNI` module in CMake determines if Java is installed and where the include files and libraries are.
Some features like AWT are not in the Jvm bundled with the Android.
The solution is to remove the `REQUIRED` argument and check if your variable is set.

```
find_package(JNI)
if (NOT JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to find Java include path.")
endif()
```

Starting with CMake `3.24` this is no longer an issue. The latest CMake version detects if the platform is Android and marks components not in Android as not required. So that you can use `find_library(JNI REQUIRED)` as usual, consider updating the CMake version to the latest to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY
  JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindJNI.cmake:382 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)
```

Update the `cmake` if you are trying in `virtualenv` check have you installed `cmake` or not.
Install `cmake` version `cmake-3.26.4-h96355d8_0`

```
conda install cmake
```

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).